# Is there a way to give context to a JSON.parse reviver?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

So I am formatting data inside JSON Strings and I need to use my application context (like this.name etc.) INSIDE the reviver.

Code example of reviver:

```
formatReviver = function (key, value) {

 if(context.name === value)
 //do stuff

}
```

But obviously THIS does not work inside the Reviver.

An idea I had is to use default values inside the parameter:

```
formatReviver = function (key, value, context = window) {

 if(context.name === value)
 //do stuff

}
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind the reviver to the current context.

```
formatReviver = (function (key, value) {
 if(this.name === value)
 //do stuff

}).bind(this)
```

Or use an arrow function, it automatically binds `this`.

```
formatReviver = (key, value) => {
 if(this.name === value)
 //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Was on vacation. Thank you. Your first solution did the trick for me.